# Python: Is there a different between ' and " in strings?

Tags: python, string

In PHP there is a difference:

```
$var='text';
'$var' → $var
"$var" → text
```

In some other languages:

```
'c' → single char
"string" → multiple chars
```

and in Python?

Comment: @heinst, I don't agree that this is a duplicate. The referenced question asks if there is a stylistic difference, this question appears to be asking if there is a semantic difference.

Comment: Those answers refer to the Docs that say there is no difference, that it's all style @Duncan

Comment: @Duncan I think it is very clear from the numerous answers in the other link that there is no semantic difference between the two

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference whatsoever, it is just a style preference.

Comment: If you print your code you will use up less printer ink if you use single quotes . :-)